# Element is not attached to a document html2canvas

Tags: reactjs

What is the meaning of this error? and how to fix it

I  try convert html data to canvas with `html2canvas`.

my code:

```
 html2canvas(ReactHtmlParser(pages[a])).then(function(canvas) {
     console.log(canvas);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically what you want to do is to get a `canvas` from your react DOM.

Now what you should do is to give normal DOM to `html2canvas(normalHTMLDomFromJS)`.

But what you are doing is to pass reactDOM(wich is javascript plain objects) to `html2canvas`

`Element is not attached to a document html2canvas` happens when you pass something except jsDOM to `html2canvas(shouldNotBeJSDOMToThrowError)` which means that `ReactHtmlParser(pages[a])`
is not returning js DOM(its returning react DOM(something like {}))

I suppose You are doing this is a react app so you must get a `ref` from your element then you can access your normal js DOM from `ref.current`

[github issue](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1313)

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function captureScreenshot(rootElem) {
    alert("Now.. Preparing Screenshot");
    console.log(rootElem);

    html2canvas(rootElem).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });
}

function App(props) {
    const rootRef = useRef(null);
    const onClick = () => {
        const elements = rootRef.current;
        captureScreenshot(elements);
    };

    return (
        <div ref={rootRef}>
            <h2 style={{ color: "pink" }}>bla bla bla</h2>
            <button onClick={onClick}>ScreenShot</button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I can not use for string of HTML? I do not want to show it in the same document! I want to add canvas to another function to save the image.

Comment: Error is because you are passing react DOM( simple objects ) to html2canvas you must use ref or give a id to you element and do it like this html2canvas(document.getElementById("my-id)) and with your canvas you can     html2canvas(rootElem).then(canvas => {
       saveImage(canvas);
});